# Merge lists in Ansible when a key/value pair from each matches

Tags: ansible

I have two lists of dictionaries (port_info and int_trunk) that I am trying to merge when the value of the 'port' key matches however not every port will be represented in 'int_trunk'.  In this instance, just leave the 'trunked_vlans' value blank.  I am using 'with_nested' to iterate over the lists.  I can't seem to get the output to do what I want.  I have tried the combine() filter along with manually trying to create vars but can't quite get it.  How do I get these two lists to combine?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    trunk_ports: []
    non_trunk_ports: []
    new_port_info: []
    port_info: 
      - desc: "*** Voice Server Port ***"
        duplex: "a-full"
        port: "Gi1/0/1"
        speed: "a-1000"
        status: connected
        trunk_vlans: ""
        type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
        vlan: 3
      - desc: "*** Voice Server Port ***"
        duplex: "a-full"
        port: "Gi1/0/2"
        speed: "a-1000"
        status: connected
        trunk_vlans: ""
        type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
        vlan: 3
      - desc: "Some Port"
        duplex: auto
        port: "Gi1/0/3"
        speed: auto
        status: notconnect
        trunk_vlans: ""
        type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
        vlan: 23
    int_trunk:
      - port: "Gi1/0/1"
        vlans: "1-50"
      - port: "Gi1/0/2"
        vlans: "50-60"
```

The output of this should be:

```
port_info: 
  - desc: "*** Voice Server Port ***"
    duplex: "a-full"
    port: "Gi1/0/1"
    speed: "a-1000"
    status: connected
    trunk_vlans: "1-50"
    type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
    vlan: 3
  - desc: "*** Voice Server Port ***"
    duplex: "a-full"
    port: "Gi1/0/2"
    speed: "a-1000"
    status: connected
    trunk_vlans: "50-60"
    type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
    vlan: 3
  - desc: "Some Port"
    duplex: auto
    port: "Gi1/0/3"
    speed: auto
    status: notconnect
    trunk_vlans: ""
    type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
    vlan: 23
```

This is one of the things I have tried:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    trunk_ports: []
    non_trunk_ports: []
    new_port_info: []
    port_info: 
      - desc: "*** Voice Server Port ***"
        duplex: "a-full"
        port: "Gi1/0/1"
        speed: "a-1000"
        status: connected
        trunk_vlans: ""
        type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
        vlan: 3
      - desc: "*** Voice Server Port ***"
        duplex: "a-full"
        port: "Gi1/0/2"
        speed: "a-1000"
        status: connected
        trunk_vlans: ""
        type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
        vlan: 3
      - desc: " "
        duplex: auto
        port: "Gi1/0/3"
        speed: auto
        status: notconnect
        trunk_vlans: ""
        type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
        vlan: 23
    int_trunk:
      - port: "Gi1/0/1"
        vlans: "1-50"
      - port: "Gi1/0/2"
        vlans: "50-60"

  tasks:
    - name: Merge trunk ports
      set_fact:
        trunk_ports: "{{ trunk_ports + [ { 'desc': item.0.desc, 'duplex': item.0.duplex, 'port': item.0.port, 'speed': item.0.speed, 'status
': item.0.status, 'trunk_vlans': item.1.vlans, 'type': item.0.type, 'vlan': item.0.vlan } ] }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ port_info }}"
        - "{{ int_trunk }}"
      when: item.0.port == item.1.port 

    - name: Merge non-trunk ports
      set_fact:
        non_trunk_ports: "{{ non_trunk_ports + [ { 'desc': item.0.desc, 'duplex': item.0.duplex, 'port': item.0.port, 'speed': item.0.speed,
 'status': item.0.status, 'trunk_vlans': item.0.trunk_vlans, 'type': item.0.type, 'vlan': item.0.vlan } ] }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ port_info }}"
        - "{{ int_trunk }}"
      when: item.0.port != item.1.port

    - name: Merge all ports
      set_fact:
        new_port_info: "{{ new_port_info + [item.0|combine(item.1)] }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ port_info }}"
        - "{{ trunk_ports }}"
      when: item.0.port == item.1.port

    - name: Echo
      debug: var=trunk_ports


    - name: Echo
      debug: var=non_trunk_ports

    - name: Echo
      debug: var=new_port_info
```

I end up with ports Gi1/0/1 and Gi1/0/2 but not Gi1/0/3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is a "one line" filtering that could do this. Here is something i came up with, explanations of the flow first:

1. we populate a list of all ports that are common in the 2 lists, using 2 `set_fact` steps.
2. we parse the 2 lists together, and when the element from `port_info` has port attribute equal to the element from `int_trunk`, we combine/merge the 2 dictionaries.
3. merge of common entries is done. now we need to parse the `port_info` list once again, and add to the `port_info_final` list all elements that have no matching element in the `int_trunk`.

We got both merged elements and unique elements in the `port_info_final` list.

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    trunk_ports: []
    non_trunk_ports: []
    new_port_info: []
    port_info: 
      - desc: "*** Voice Server Port ***"
        duplex: "a-full"
        port: "Gi1/0/1"
        speed: "a-1000"
        status: connected
        trunk_vlans: ""
        type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
        vlan: 3
      - desc: "*** Voice Server Port ***"
        duplex: "a-full"
        port: "Gi1/0/2"
        speed: "a-1000"
        status: connected
        trunk_vlans: ""
        type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
        vlan: 3
      - desc: "Some Port"
        duplex: auto
        port: "Gi1/0/3"
        speed: auto
        status: notconnect
        trunk_vlans: ""
        type: "10/100/1000BaseTX"
        vlan: 23
    int_trunk:
      - port: "Gi1/0/1"
        vlans: "1-50"
      - port: "Gi1/0/2"
        vlans: "50-60"
    port_info_final: []

  tasks:

  - name: get the lists of ports per list
    set_fact:
      portlist_1: "{{ port_info | map(attribute='port') | list }}"
      portlist_2: "{{ int_trunk | map(attribute='port') | list }}"

  - name: get the ports that exist in port_info but not in int_trunk
    set_fact:
      ports_not_in_int_trunk: "{{ portlist_1 | difference(portlist_2) }}"

  - name: merge the dictionaries when the port is matched
    set_fact:
      port_info_final: "{{ port_info_final + [item[0] | combine(item[1])] }}"
    when: item[0].port == item[1].port
    loop: "{{ query('nested', int_trunk, port_info) }}"

  - name: add all the port_info elements that dont have entry in int_trunk
    set_fact:
      port_info_final: "{{ port_info_final + [item] }}"
    when: item.port in ports_not_in_int_trunk
    loop: "{{ port_info }}"

  - name: print results
    debug:
      msg: "{{ port_info_final }}"
```

result:

```
TASK [print results] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "desc": "*** Voice Server Port ***", 
            "duplex": "a-full", 
            "port": "Gi1/0/1", 
            "speed": "a-1000", 
            "status": "connected", 
            "trunk_vlans": "", 
            "type": "10/100/1000BaseTX", 
            "vlan": 3, 
            "vlans": "1-50"
        }, 
        {
            "desc": "*** Voice Server Port ***", 
            "duplex": "a-full", 
            "port": "Gi1/0/2", 
            "speed": "a-1000", 
            "status": "connected", 
            "trunk_vlans": "", 
            "type": "10/100/1000BaseTX", 
            "vlan": 3, 
            "vlans": "50-60"
        }, 
        {
            "desc": "Some Port", 
            "duplex": "auto", 
            "port": "Gi1/0/3", 
            "speed": "auto", 
            "status": "notconnect", 
            "trunk_vlans": "", 
            "type": "10/100/1000BaseTX", 
            "vlan": 23
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

hope it helps

Comment: This works although I had to make a slight modification due to my own error in the input I provided.  In port_info, we have "trunked_vlans" which starts out with no value.  In int_trunk, we have "vlans".  I wanted "vlans" to be combined with "trunked_vlans" and not create a new k/v pair.  So what I did was renamed "vlans" to "trunked_vlans" then reversed the lists in the combine loop so that int_trunk keys override port_info keys.  That seems to do what I want.  Thanks!